# How to create an Athena table with columns made of dictionaries of strings and numbers?

Tags: python, amazon-athena

Consider the following example value of the column `mycol` contained in my Pandas dataframe. `df.mycol.iloc[0]` would show as:

```
array([array([{'Code': '123', 'Category': 3},
              {'Code': '343', 'Category': 5}],
             dtype=object)                                                                                                                        ],
      dtype=object)
```

The data lives on parquet files that I want to make available to `Athena`. Unfortunately, I have a very hard time finding what the correct `Athena` **type** is for this column. As you know, typing down the exact data type is required when using the `Athena` creation query command:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable`.`thistable` ( `mycol` string) ROW FORMAT SERDE
```

Obviously `mycol` is not a string. But what is it precisely? A struct? if so how can I define it correctly?

Thanks!